# swift: programmatically create variable name

Tags: swift

New to Swift (coming from JS and, um, z80/68k assembly) is there a way to do this with a loop rather than writing them all out? I've tried a few approaches, but it's been difficult to google this exact situation...

I need these sample names as AVplayers (due to the nature of the app they need their own player due to heavy manipulation of the samples - think like a MOD player):

```
let tracks:[String] = ["bgcar","bgrain","bgtent","bgtrain","city","crickets","fan","fire","hoover","plane","roof","sea","storm","underwater","water","wind"]
```

So have then written them out also as avplayers:

```
var bgcar : AVAudioPlayer?
var bgrain : AVAudioPlayer?
var bgtent : AVAudioPlayer?
var bgtrain : AVAudioPlayer?
var city : AVAudioPlayer?
var crickets : AVAudioPlayer?
var fan : AVAudioPlayer?
var fire : AVAudioPlayer?
var hoover : AVAudioPlayer?
var plane : AVAudioPlayer?
var roof : AVAudioPlayer?
var sea : AVAudioPlayer?
var storm : AVAudioPlayer?
var underwater : AVAudioPlayer?
var water : AVAudioPlayer?
var wind : AVAudioPlayer?
```

But I feel it must be possible to create these from the array? So I can just add more with one edit?

I've tried a loop but can't find the right syntax to create from the array names :(

I've also found people saying this isn't possible, but I want to make sure as it's ugly code IMO.

Comment: Most languages support a "dictionary" that allows key/value pairs that can work generally for what someone is trying to do when they ask for dynamically named variables. [Swift Dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary)

Answer (score -1):

after some googling around I managed to find a similar solution as so:

First define the avplayers as an array:

```
var soundPlayers: [AVAudioPlayer] = []
```

Then in your main code:

```
let tracks:[String] =["bgcar","bgrain","bgtent","bgtrain","city","crickets","fan","fire","hoover","plane","roof","sea","storm","underwater","water","wind"]



for track in tracks {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "/assets/"+track, withExtension: "m4a") else {
           print("url not found:")
           return
       }


    do{
    let soundPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
                    soundPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
                    soundPlayer.volume = 1
                    //soundPlayer.play()
                    soundPlayers.append( soundPlayer )
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("BG error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    }
```

Now you have an array of the players which you can set a variable to correctly reference (via a function or name or whatever).

Hope this might help someone!

Comment: Hi Jimmy, It seems to me that this answer is not an answer to the question you asked. Maybe you would like to redefine the question?